# How to learn pocketsphinx for bi-lingual system?

Tags: machine-learning, cmusphinx, pocketsphinx, language-model, phonetics

I did create a dictionary with 2 languages(English/Persian) at the one file like this:

```
بگو        B E G U
خزنده        KH A Z A N D E
قدت        GH A D E T
چنده        CH A N D E
قد         GH A D
من        M A N
شب        SH A B
hi        H AA Y
hello        H E L L O
how        H O V
are        AA R
you        Y U
what         V AA T
is         I Z
your         Y O R
name        N E Y M
old        O L D
where         V E R
from        F E R AA M
```

And used http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/tools/lmtool-new.html to build the language model. Then I tried to learn an acoustic model with that language model and test it.

It works good for Persian voices but doesn't work for English words. After some try&error I found that the problem is about my phoneset. I used my own phoneset as you can see above, but it seems pocketsphinx doesn't accept this phoneset for English words and it only accepts it's own phoneset for English!

So I want to know did I found the problem true? Should I use the pocketsphinx phoneset for my Persian words as well? Where should I find it's complete phoneset and a guide to learn how to use it for Persian words?

Answer (score 0):

You have to build a new acoustic model with joined phoneset